# Comodo Antivirus - Fails to update signature database

Tags: virus, anti-virus, updates, comodo-firewall

I am using Comodo Internet Security including Antivirus v5.8.213334.2131 Free version. Virus signature database v 25399.  OS Windows XP Sp3

I am trying to update this signature online. It downloads the latest parches as usual and starts applying but prolongs at 90% for over 5 minutes and then pops up a message stating   **‘Failed to update the virus signature database. Please check your internet connection and try again later’**

Apparently the internet connection is just fine. This message appears misleading. I have tried several times over last couple of days but same result. Very little info is available on Comodo Forums. A user who faced similar problem was able to solve it by re-installing the anti virus.

I tried complete uninstall and fresh install but the error exists. Even I tried to force a full download of database (by pushing a very old version of bases.cav file as current) but it fails at ‘Finalizing’ stage at 90%. I even ran built in Comodo Diagnostics utility and it did not report anything.

Does anyone know what’s going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to go to comodo folder scanners and create a bat with this:

@echo off

SET "FILENAME=%~dp0\newbases.cav"

bitsadmin.exe /transfer "database" http://download.comodo.com/av/updates51/sigs/bases/bases.cav?track=6138 "%FILENAME%"

DEL bases.cav.b

ren bases.cav bases.cav.b

ren newbases.cav bases.cav

Then go to windows task manager and create a task to executev the bat at boot with administrator previlages.

You will see that updates go fine after that.

.

Answer (score 0):

The complete Comodo Internet Security database is available for download. This is useful for those users that wish to manually replace the existing database or would like access to the database for other reasons. The complete, downloadable database is updated approximately every 2 days so may not contain all the latest definitions as shown in the table above.

For users of Comodo Antivirus or Internet Security 5.8 & newer :
http://download.comodo.com/av/updates58/sigs/bases/bases.cav?track=6137v&s_track=7639

For users of Comodo Antivirus or Internet Security 5.5 & older :
http://download.comodo.com/av/updates51/sigs/bases/bases.cav?track=6138&s_track=7639

Hope it will fix your problem.

Best Regards!
Kashaf Muzaffar
Senior IT Professional

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Generally, a signature line isn't appropriate on answers.  However, if you're answering as a Comodo representative, that is important to explicitly specify because it goes to your expertise and makes the answer more authoritative.

Answer (score 0):

To download go to this link on Comodo's website:

https://www.comodo.com/home/internet-security/updates/vdp/database.php

They are the same links as Kashaf Muzaffar shared, but, I am sharing the link in case something changes in the future, so, you will be able to find always the latest links there.

Now, and because you may be saying and asking... "Okay, I got the database, no what?"

An Step by step instructions on how manually update CIS definitions please use the link below:

https://forums.comodo.com/antivirus-faq/where-can-i-download-the-latest-full-av-database-t47164.0.html?s_track=7639

Answer (score 0):

You can add mirrors for updates:

```
http://cdn.download.comodo.com/
http://downloads.comodo.com/
http://download-cn.comodo.com/
```

More about it is written here: https://windowsreport.com/comodo-antivirus-not-updating/